# Reactjs application image not working in kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, github-actions

I am hosting my reactjs-redux application to kubernetes via GitHub action. The pipeline is successful but after the deployment I am only seeing the below Nginx screen. I feel the issue is with the kubernetes. Can someone please help me on this

[image]

My Kubernetes manifest is given below

**deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-dev
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: artifactory.com:2195/myapp:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "3"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 128Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp


My Github action step is as given below

      publish:
        name: Upload to Artifactory
        needs: 
          - build
        runs-on: self-hosted
        container:
          image: artifactory.com:2005/ubuntu-docker-kubectl:1.0
        steps:
          - name: Checkouting project
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
          - name: Login to On-Prem Registry
            uses: actions/login-action@v1
            with:
              registry: artifactory.com:2195/artifactory
              username: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}
              password: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}
    
          - name: Build and push image to Artifactory
            uses: actions/build-push-action@v2
            with:
              file: 'Dockerfile'
              push: true
              tags: "artifactory.com:2195/myapp:latest"
```

**service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-dev
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

**ingress.yml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-dev
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev-myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-dev
                port:
                  number: 80
```

## Update 1

As per the discussion with [@Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) the docker image is fine, we are able to run successfully in the localhost. So the issue is with the Kubernetes deployment.

Can someone please help me on this

Comment: Is your starting page called `index.html`? It needs to be for the default nginx config to work.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes....I have updated the SO

Comment: I don't like the `--if-present` flag. If there's no build script, wouldn't you want the Docker build to fail rather than succeed? Since it's there, can you check that there is a `build` script in the package.json file?

Comment: @HansKilian This is what I'm having in package.json `"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8000 build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md,html,css,less,scss}\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },`

Comment: OK, so it's not that. Can you run `docker run --rm <image name> ls -al /usr/share/nginx/html` to check what files are in the html directory?

Comment: @HansKilian here is the files https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9go2.png

Comment: So your files are in the image. Then it must be that your image isn't deployed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243643/discussion-between-alex-man-and-hans-kilian).

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this in your dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY /usr/src/app/build/ .
```